# drawing an arrow by month through multiple points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very small dataset

```
cent<-structure(list(temporal = structure(c(3L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
2L), .Label = c("April", "August", "February", "July", "June", 
"March", "May"), class = "factor"), NMDS1 = c(0.0974540266588284, 
0.1688532488445, 0.0468643826727811, 0.0355451066297488, -0.0209516885503105, 
-0.206936981483144, -0.120828094772404), NMDS2 = c(-0.0101014005049961, 
0.030236007628167, -0.388205968271465, -0.166511878199233, -0.0172718994833608, 
0.321810567323985, 0.230044571506903)), row.names = c(3L, 6L, 
1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L), class = "data.frame")
```

This data represents centroid positions of a nmds analysis for every month. I want to plot this with ggplot (which is simple enough):

```
ggplot(cent, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, colour = factor(temporal, levels = month.name))) +
  geom_line(arrow = arrow()) +# spiders
  geom_point(data = cent, size = 5) +                         
  geom_point() +                                              
  coord_fixed() + theme_classic()
```

But I want to draw an arrow that connects all points (in order by month) to show how these centroids change over time. I have not been able to figure out how to do this and I'm about to just throw it in MS paint and do it on there. Any help would really help!

Just some context, I sampled for insects every month (10 same sites each month) and ran a non-metric multidimensional scaling analysis on the data. I calculated centroids based on months and want to show how much the community is shifting and changing over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)
ggplot(cent, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, colour = factor(temporal, levels = month.name))) +
  geom_line(arrow = arrow()) +# spiders
  geom_point(data = cent, size = 5) +     
  geom_segment(aes(xend = lead(NMDS1), yend = lead(NMDS2)), 
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.05,"npc"), type = "closed")) +
  coord_fixed() + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, this code will help for the future as well